# Return column name of max value in a row SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Initial Table:

```
    Name    Job1    Job2     Job3     Job4     Job5     Job6
--------------------------------------------------------------
    A        34       0        66      0        0       0
    B        33       33       33      1        0       0
    C        100      0         0      0        0       0
    D        50       0         0      0        0       50
```

Output Table:

```
    Name    Max           Job1     Job2     Job3     Job4     Job5     Job6
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    A       Job3            34       0        66      0        0       0
    B       Job1;Job2;Job3  33       33       33      1        0       0
    C       Job1            100      0         0      0        0       0
    D       Job1;Job6       50       0         0      0        0       50
```

I need to get the Job Name (column name) of the row with the max value in SQL Server.
Is there a way other than else if to do this because 'greatest' function is not available in SQL? (Coz I have 50 Jobs at least)

Comment: Fix your design, *that* is the solution. There should be 1 job column, not 50.

Comment: As @Larnu said your design is not the best, but if you have to do it this way for these tables I suggest inserting into temp/working table first with each Name and all jobs in separate rows, then do max.  Or use CASE statements (but that is not good and slow)

Comment: Actually, i have people in different divisions. So Div1 has Job1/2/3 and other jobs are NULL, Div2 has Job1/2/3/5/6 and so on. And every person has different outputs in each job. So either I can have multiple rows with each row having one Job and capacity or I can have a design like this. So, case statements are making it too slow.

Comment: *"So either I can have multiple rows with each row having one Job and capacity"* And that is **exactly** what you should be going. `MAX(JobValue)` is significantly easier than `(SELECT MAX(JobValue) FROM (VALUES(Job1, Job2, Job3, ... Job49, Job50)V(JobValue))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` and window functions:

```
select t.*, max_cols
from t cross apply
     (select string_agg(colname, ';') as max_cols
      from (select top (1) with ties v.colname
            from (values ('Job1', t.job1), ('Job2', t.job2), . . . 
                 ) v(colname, job)
            order by v.job desc
           ) v
     ) v;
```

That said, you should probably fix your data model.  Having multiple columns with the same information is usually a sign of a deficient data model.  Each `name`/`job` combination should be a separate row in another table.